# Space of Tangent and Bitangent Vectors

Tags: vector, spaces

I have a really simple question I cannot be sure about the answer.

What is the space of tangent (T), and bitangent (B) vectors when we calculate them using vertex positions, and texture coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your vertices haven't been multiplied by any matrices the tangent and bitangent will be in object space.

Edit:

Your vertices are in object space. A normal is a vector perpendicular to a face (usually a triangle made from 3 vertices). Because the vertices used to calculate the normal are in object space, the normal will be also. The same follows for the tangent and bitangent.

Comment: Yes, I am not transforming my vertices into other coordinate system.

Could you please give some details why they will be in object space?